# Need An Idea Of How To Setup This TCP/UDP Framework

Tags: java, sockets, frameworks, protocols, netty

I am asking this as I am attempting to create a game library and I am kind of new to Socket programming and I was wondering if it is best that I use netty or plain old Socket.io for this. And when attempting this I just need an idea of how I should go about mixing TCP/UDP together within my framework for this section of what I am working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you already picked netty, at least as tag. With that framework you do not do socket programming yourself. Go through the documentation and learn to focus on event handlers: What should happen when a message is received via the network?

Consider such messages simply to be events, just like a mouse click or keyboard input.